# How to upload NamedTemporaryFile via FileField in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a `NamedTemporaryFile` which I wish to upload by updating my `Django` model. Below is how I am creating the `NamedTemporaryFile`. I am updating the file through `csv.writer`

```
error_file = open(tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile().name, 'w+', newline='')
```

The model is like below:

```
class Logs(models.Model):
    error_file = models.FileField(upload_to='errors/', blank=True, null=True, max_length=200)
```

I am trying to upload the `error_file` to the errors directory.

```
from django.core.files.base import File
l = Logs.objects.get(pk=1)

error_file.seek(0) # I seek the cursor to the starting position before saving
l.error_file.save('error1.csv', File(error_file))
```

Below is the error I am getting:

> AttributeError: 'File' object has no attribute 'temporary_file_path'

How can I upload the `NamedTemporaryFile` or is there any other way to do it. Thank you.